# Windows Update causing server meltdown

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, update

A failed windows update caused my Windows Server 2012 R2 install to have a meltdown.

Update package:

> Microsoft-Windows-NetFx4-OC-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.9600.16384

failed and every time the computer reboots it says "Installing Updates 35%" then reboots and says it was unable to install updates and attempts to undo changes.  I also no longer have access to roles and features and am getting the error:
"Online - Cannot get role and feature data".

If I try running

> "sfc /scannow"

it says "There is a system repair pending which requires reboot to complete". and rebooting Windows obviously doesn't help.

I also tried running:

> dism /online /remove-package /packagename:Microsoft-Windows-NetFx4-OC-
>   Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.9600.16384"

Which fails with:

> Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
>   Version: 6.3.9600.17031
>
> Image Version: 6.3.9600.17031
>
> Processing 1 of 1 - An error occurred - Microsoft-Windows-NetFx4-OC-Package >Error: 0x80070005
>
> Error: 5
>
> Access is denied.
>
> The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: sfc is your best bet. Start in safe mode Look for pending.xml or reboot.xml in the c:\windows\system32 and rename then reboot and try sfc /scannow

Comment: Did that and now I'm getting:


Role and feature refresh failed with the following error: The request to list features available on the specified server failed.  Unable to obtain the feature list.  The component store has been corrupted. Error 0x80073712

Comment: Having same issue as what's reported here [link](http://superuser.com/questions/773630/dism-startcomponentcleanup-fails-but-scanhealth-reports-healthy)

Comment: share the folder **C:\windows\logs\CBS** as zip on cloud service.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/957310 follow the Windows 8.1 instructions.